# Sizing buttons in menu in the correct way

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm doing a menu. The problem is that my buttons are too close to one another. I would like to separate them a bit.
Also I would like to extend them (rozszerzyć je) to the similar sizes.

Here you have the code:

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Here you have the image of this problem:

[image: (rysunek)]

And each button out of the 4 ones has a similar code. (the difference is in layout_above.

How to make it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you have to use a `RelativeLayout`? If you can use a `LinearLayout` I'd use something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..."
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding_top="4dp"
        android:padding_bottom="4dp"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

This would get all your buttons to be the same size horizontal and vertical. You can tweak the padding top and bottom to get the desired effect.

The way `layout_weight` works is it takes the leftover space of the parent view, and portions them out to the children views according to their weights. Since the height of every button is `0dp`, 100% of the vertical space is left to partition out. Since the weight of all the buttons is the same, they will be roughly the same size.

This explanation is for a vertical `LinearLayout`. For a horizontal, just switch the values of `layout_height` and `layout_width`.